# замена элементов в списке по индексу. Python

Tags: python, list, циклы

Есть задание, в существующий список внести значения пользователя.
Никак не получается это сделать.
Должно быть циклом до тех пор пока пользователь не введет в поле индекс : `"-1"`

Cпасибо

Вот пример:

`list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Введите индекс: 0

Введите значение: 10

`[10, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Введите индекс: 2

Введите значение: 250

`[10, 2, 250, 4, 5]`

Введите индекс: -1

Моя попытка:

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5]
        
    for i in list:
        index=int(input("Введите индекс: "))
        arv=int(input("Введите значение: "))
        if index >= 0:
               list.insert(index, arv)
               print(list)
        if index<0:
            break
```

Comment: добавлять или заменять значение по индексу? и не используйте резервные имена, в вашем случае `list`

Comment: `list[index] = arv` **P.S.** `list` плохое название для переменной, т.к. совпадает с функцией. Это может привести к странным багам. Назовите, например, как `items`

Comment: Необходимо заменить значения из списка на значения введеные пользователем. Заменять значения как примере...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in a:
    index = int(input("Введите индекс: "))

    if index < 0:
        break
    else:
        arv = int(input("Введите значение: "))
        del a[index]
        a.insert(index, arv)
        print(a)
```

- вместо `list` используем другое название переменной
- явно укажем что `-1` может быть меньше нуля
- ввод `arv` перенесём после проверки индекса
- сначала удалим значение по индексу
- после добавим значение по индексу

Comment: Спасибо !!! Понял !!

Comment: Зачем делать `del` и потом `insert`, если можно просто заменить элемент `a[index] = arv`

Comment: чтобы было общее понимание, скорее логическое, что просто `insert` не сработает.

Answer (score 3):

Согласна с @Violet, что `list` необходимо заменить на другое имя переменной, например, `a`, т.к. `list` - зарезервированное слово.

Однако я бы использовала цикл `while`

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

while True:
    index = int(input("Введите индекс: "))

    if index < 0:
        break
    
    val = int(input("Введите значение: "))
    a[index] = val
```

Возможно имеет смысл проверять, чтобы индекс не выходил за границы массива:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l = len(a) # Длина массива
while True:
    index = int(input("Введите индекс: "))

    if index < 0:
        break
    
    if index >= l:
      print("Индекс выходит за границы массива")
      continue 

    val = int(input("Введите значение: "))
    a[index] = val
```

Comment: `else` тут можно не писать, из-за `break`. И сделайте правда проверку на выход индекса за границу, будет совсем красиво

Comment: `l` - плохое название для переменной, очень похоже на число `1` )  Я бы не экономил на спичках в данном случае и не заводил отдельную переменную под `len(a)`, если код не упирается в производительность

Comment: Вот для меня это всегда дилемма: когда надо выносить такие вещи в отдельную переменную, а когда их лучше считать каждый раз

Comment: Всё просто. Если длина коллекции может измениться, либо если скорость кода не критична - считать каждый раз (либо обновлять в том месте, где меняется коллекция - смотря что оптимальнее в конкретном коде). Если длина коллекции не может измениться и данных так много, что в коде дорога каждая миллисекунда - выносить такие вычисляемые штуки за циклы, в переменные.